# idiom for 'Don't give up the day job'

Tags: idiom

One of my favourite phrases is 'Don't give up the day job' for when someone is not very good at something. I put together 'Noli labor a die dedere'. However 'labor' is more 'task' instead of 'job' and would like a better alternative for 'by day'. Could anyone give me a better translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adjective for “day …” or “daily” would be *diurnus*. But you are being a bit too literal. It is a peculiarity of English that a person's regular occupation is called their “day job.” I think *negotium* fits the bill.

Likewise, *dedere* is not a good fit either, it means “surrender, yield,” etc.

So I would suggest:

> Retine negotium.
>
> *Keep the day job.*

or less terse:

> Interim retine tuum negotium.
>
> *For the time being, keep your day job.*